# How can i export Skype Chat history to a text file or other readable file in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, skype

I want to be able to export my chat history so I can read it outside of Skype and save it permanently somewhere else. I have seen many suggestion about main.db file in skype directory but unable to find that file in Ubuntu 13.04 or if however i found main.db file so how can i convert in text file.

Please let me know you suggestion.

Comment: Have you had a look at this > [Copy skype chat history to text files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149214/copy-skype-chat-history-to-text-files)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Right click in a chat window → Select All or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
3. Paste it into a file of your choice.

The output will be something like this:

```
[7:39:36 AM] destiny: pingu pingu
[7:39:46 AM] name: pingu to you as well
[7:39:54 AM] destiny: pingu to everyone
[7:39:55 AM] destiny: i see
[7:40:02 AM] destiny: so pingu to u
[7:40:12 AM] name: ok...?
[7:40:19 AM] destiny: :D
[7:41:08 AM] destiny: pingu 1234
```

Comment: That is really obsolete or hadn't been useful in the first place.

Comment: I don't think Skype never showed the entire log, so this would save only the most recent logs. If you first scroll up to the beginning of the log (which could take a day or two), this might work, but I'm skeptical even then, for large logs.